# Opening two projects at once in one QGIS window

Tags: qgis

is it possible to have open two gis projects at once within QGIS?

I want to compare the position of points between two different coordinate reference systems.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately not.

It was something that I did consider looking at adding support for but currently it would be a lot of work the way the code is structured.  Also raises a lot of usability issues that would need to be resolved to make it friendly.